# android studio - fail to build project after Material dependency upgrade

Tags: java, android, gradle, material-ui, material-components-android

The requirement is to upgrade all gradle dependencies of an old android app.
Managed to upgrade all to latest and is able to build and run the app.
When I upgraded the `Material` dependency from `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` to the latest `com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0` I got the following error:

`Illegal char <:> at index 56: app.com.my.app-mergeMyAppDebugResources-50:/values/values.xml`

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeMyAppDebugResources'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file S:\Work\android\app\app_newImpl2023-12-27\app.com.my.app.android\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\MyAppDebug\mergeMyAppDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 56: app.com.my.app-mergeMyAppDebugResources-50:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details

I have looked into most if not all SO questions that are related to build error - illegal char. But non solved my problem. Which only appears when `Material` is upgraded.

**Build gradle (:app) dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.3'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    // Required for instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation 'ru.noties:debug:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    implementation 'com.flipkart.springyheads:library:0.9.6'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    //social media login
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'
} 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**What I have tried:**

1- Invalidate cache.

2- Looked into Strings file for illegal <:>. found couple of strings that has :, removed all of them to try to build the project, still didn't work.

3- colors file doesn't have any : character.

4- styles file has something like `<item name="android:buttonStyle">? android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle</item>` Which I commented to try to build, but again same error.

5- In merged `values` file the char <:> is repeated more than 2000 times which makes it very difficult to check where the problem is.

6- there's no attr file under `values` folder

**My questions:** 
1-What causes merged `values` file error when upgrading the material dependency?

2- Where should I start to try and debug this problem other than what I have tried already.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question..

What I did to try and get more info about this error is:

1. Install android studio on mac book (Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1).
2. run the app to make sure all is good before upgrading material dependency.
3. Upgrade Material to latest `com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0`
4. Build the project. I got more detailed error including the line inside the `values` file.
5. The error shows a duplicate declaration of `TextInputEditText`. I searched inside the file and found this is declared in both `Material` and another dependency `com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.4.4`
6. Commented this dependency in gradle file, sync then was able to successfully build the project.

Thanks